# Unable to change network connection

Tags: networking, vpn, xfce, vnc

Today I started configure VNC on my VPS. My VPS is ubuntu server 18.04 and everything passed very well, until I started configure VPN connection on xfce.

First of all I had problem with greyed out options in network manager, but I resolved this through installing network-manager-openvpn etc.
Now I am standing front of wall, because I can't choose my custom network options.

Network Manager VPN options:

[image: network manager vpn options]

Current network installations:

[image: installed packages]

My goal is to set up l2tp network connection.